# Why is my jsfiddle Javascript class not defined?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

HTML:

```
<img src="https://help.pace.edu/helpdesk/info_icon_small.gif?v=12_1_0_300.gif" onclick="plusButton_Click()">
```

js:

```
function plusButton_Click() {  
    alert('hi');    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uEypH/1/

I might be new to Javascript and all. But why does my Firefox console say

`"ReferenceError: plusButton_Click is not defined"?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function must be in global scope if you intend to call it in inline js.

jsfiddle creates a new closure, so it is not global. Use their `--wrap it in head--` option.

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uEypH/2/)

Or change

```
function plusButton_Click() {  
    alert('hi');    
}
```

to:

```
window.plusButton_Click = function(){
   alert('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have javascript set to onLoad.  In a normal page, you would have put it straight in the body most likely.  Set it to NoWrap  and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

By default, jsFiddle places your Javascript code into an `onLoad` function. Your `plusButton_Click` will not be visible outside of this closure.

To fix, either:

- Select "In `<head>`" from the dropdown ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QkwJ3/))
- Define your function as `window.plusButton_Click = function() { ... }` ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6PV/))