# jsFiddle doesn't recognize classes?

Tags: javascript

Originally reported here: [Why is my jsfiddle Javascript class not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567375/why-is-my-jsfiddle-javascript-class-not-defined)

However, upon my implementation, I'm seeing similar behavior but none of the answers appear to apply.

```
foo();
baz = new bar();
baz.getMessage();

function foo() {
    $('#foo').html("I am foo.");
}

function bar() {
    this.message = "I am bar.";

}
bar.prototype = {
    getMessage: function() {
        $('#bar').html(this.message);
    }
};
```

Fiddle located at: http://jsfiddle.net/eggmatters/qeufnpoj/2/

Firebug reporting: "TypeError: baz.getMessage is not a function."

Comment: Only the `function` declaration is hoisted. The assignment of its `prototype` still happens after the instance is created.

Comment: This isn't a jsfiddle problem.

Comment: moving baz.getMessage after the prototype declaration still doesn't work. How is this not a jsfiddle problem? This, to my knowledge, is valid js.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I had originally wrapped the calls in $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the location of the `bar.prototype`. Specifically because it's after the creation of the instance and call and as such will not be defined yet:

```
baz = new bar();
baz.getMessage();
... 
bar.prototype = { ... }
```

Meaning that `getMessage()` was not yet defined, note that you are using an assignment `=`, meaning that `getMessage()` will not be defined until that line is reached in the code. The solution is to have `bar.prototype` be defined first:

```
bar.prototype = { ... }
...
baz = new bar();
baz.getMessage();
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qeufnpoj/6/)

Answer (score 1):

First, your JS isn't executing. If you change your JS load from "No wrap - in <head>" to "onLoad", it'll run.

Or, you can just wrap your JS in an onload function:

```
$(function() {
    ...
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
    ...
}
```

Second, you need to declare the prototype before you try to execute:

```
foo();
bar.prototype = {
    getMessage: function() {
        $('#bar').html(this.message);
    }
};
baz = new bar();
baz.getMessage();

function foo() {
    $('#foo').html("I am foo.");
}

function bar() {
    this.message = "I am bar.";

}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5drcuwx5/

Comment: Thanks! At one point, I wrapped the class as a function `function myFoo() { . . . }()` but jsfiddle complained. I feel kinda foolish now. I usually seperate my classes into scripts and include them in the order they need to be in without thinking about it.